# In Fedora how to launch a webapp from the terminal?

Tags: fedora, command, launcher

I have installed a webapp (Copilot) using edge in Fedora.
I would like to launch the app using a shortcut but I cannot find the command to launch it.
I imagine it should be a command launching the browser with some arguments but I could not find any documentation for this.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed:

```
flatpak run com.microsoft.Edge --new-window --app=https://copilot.microsoft.com
```

thanks to the answer from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748958/how-to-open-website-as-app-in-microsoft-edge-from-cli